# ReactJS doesn't save object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am currently experiencing a weird issue in React where a changed object in an array does not save.

```
changeQuantity(Product, Quantity) {
    let index = this.state.products.findIndex(p => p === Product);
    Product.Amount = Quantity;

    let productarray = this.state.products;

    productarray[index] = Product;

    console.log(index);
    console.log(productarray[index]);
    console.log(productarray);

    this.setState({
      products: productarray
    })

  }
```

`index` = 0

`productarray[index]` = has correct `Amount`

`productarray` = has wrong `Amount` (Still zero, no matter which number I put in as `Quantity`

is there anything I am missing here on why it doesn't properly save?

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try create a new array, that's how react tell if a object changed or not.

```
  oldArray[index] = anotherObject
  const newArray = [...oldArray]
  setState{ products: newArray }
```